# Stream analytics with azure function output, error writing batches

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-stream-analytics

I got a setup with a Stream analytics outputting to an Azure function, this is working partially. In Log Analytics I am getting a lot of these errors:

```
Failed to write events. Error encountered after writing [1] batches. 
Error - A task was canceled. . Error encountered after writing [1] batches. 
Error - A task was canceled. . Error encountered after writing [0] batches.
```

Any suggestions on how to find out the exact error and how to solve this?

Comment: please add the code of your a) the ASA job writing data out and b) the Function that's taking the data in. Without code it's hard to impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to investigate what the issue is without any sample code. However, what you can do is to check if ASA job has the right output, and verify connectivity to outputs by using the Test Connection button for each output.

Here are links to troubleshoot pages:

azure stream analytics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-troubleshoot-output

azure function:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-recover-storage-account